# Error 403 en directorio XAMPP

Tags: xampp

Creé un enlace simbólico de un directorio ( Q: ) donde tengo los archivos que necesito acceder mediante el servidor el comando que utilice fue mklink /D videos Q: Entonces en mi carpeta htdocs al acceder a la capeta videos puedo reproducir los videos perfectamente están en subcarpetas. Sin embargo cuando ingreso desde localhost/videos me dice que no tengo los permisos suficientes. Entonces en el httpd-conf:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Lo dejé así por cuestiones de prueba, pero igual no funciona. En el registro de errores dice:

> *[Sat May 06 14:26:29.482043 2023] [autoindex:error] [pid 7252:tid 1892] (OS 3)The system cannot find the path specified.  : [client 35.174.214.129:50330] AH01275: Can't open directory for index: C:/xampp/htdocs/videos/*

Pero al ingresar a la ruta en mi directorio de carpeta me redirige a el directorio Q:

¿Qué podría estar pasando?

Comment: Yo creo que hay confusión en esto. Donde has creado ese enlace y como tratas de llegar a el desde Apache?

Comment: Estando en el directorio C:\xampp\htdocs indiqué el comando; mklink /D videos Q: Me creó una carpeta llamada videos la cual puedo acceder al contenido de la misma sin problemas. Los archivos contenido son los que se encuentran en mi unidad Q: pero cuando ingreso a localhost/videos es donde me aparece el error de permisos

Comment: Extraño, lo he realizado como has indicado y funciona perfectamente en el explorador de archivos y desde Apache (navegador en http://localhost/videos)... Use el CMD para crear el link en modo **Administrador**. No necesité configurar nada...

Comment: Super raro, la unidad montada está con Rclone, pero como digo los archivos los puedo reproducir sin problemas desde el explorador. El problema está cuando se consultan desde el navegador. Acabe de eliminar el enlace y volví a crearlo en modo Administrador.

Comment: Y funcionó así?

Comment: Lastimosamente no. Sin embargo opté por una solución temporal que funcionó pero ya no. Monté la unidad dentro del servidor con ubuntu y bueno funcionó logré acceder a los archivos sin embargo me genera un error de recursos agotados por parte de la api. Entonces ahora estoy enfrentando ese nuevo problema